# Google GAM - remove files/folders in Google Drive older than x days

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm looking for a solution to auto-remove files and folders in Google Drive older than x days, using GAM command.

I went through GAM documentation, but don't see any command that could do that, so I'm counting on your help.
I know that I could do that with script based on Google Drive API, but I would like to stick with GAM.

Comment: GAM is a third party library. you may want to ask them directly